# How to count the number of windows (cmd.exe) opened?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I open several instances of cmd.exe at a time and I need a code in C, counting the number of instances of cmd.exe *32 windows open at the moment.

I guess I need a call to a .dll (some sort of windows api).

Thank you very much

Comment: BTW, if you used Linux, the equivalent question would be very simple (using `/proc/`)

Comment: Start reading about the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc433218(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: More likely than an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I'm guessing that you need to find out when all your spawned processes have terminated. Counting the number of *cmd.exe* processes repeatedly until that count drops to zero is a solution, provided that you can unambiguously identify your *cmd.exe* processes from any others.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes thanks. I don't know a thing about the .dll I need and what to use for this task unfortunately

Comment: "*I open several instances of cmd.exe at a time*" - If you need to detect when they end, you could create a [Job object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects), [assign your `cmd` processes to it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject), and then wait for the Job to finish. You can optionally receive notifications when each process in the Job ends, and when the Job becomes empty. See [How do I wait until all processes in a job have exited?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743)

Comment: You may want to use [EnumProcesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) or [PdhEnumObjectItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhenumobjectitemsa). Find your target process by its name and count the number of its instances.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many things. Do you create the cmd windows manually or programmatically? If programmatically, how do you create tehm? ShellExecute? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea. Returns a handle that you can test. You can also use CreateToolHelp32SnapShot, Process32First and Process32Next to test if a process is still running but that does not discriminate between your and other cmd processes.